# Using third party software within parfor loop

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

I wrote a set of nested for loops to conduct a parameter sweep in a third party software (Lumerical, it's an FDTD package) in Matlab. This code works perfectly well, but I can't seem to get the parallel version to work. My guess is that Matlab is having issues assigning workers in the parallel case, but I'm having issues resolving this. I've copied my code for the loop below and the line in the function I use to execute each Lumerical simulation. Does anyone have any suggestions for how to resolve this?

```
parfor ph = 1:PH
    for p = 1:P
     for bi = 1:BI
      for pii = 1:PI
          for r =1:R
              poolobj = gcp;
              addAttachedFiles(poolobj, FDTD_exec_pillars_parfor.m);
              pitch = [PillarHeight(ph), Pitch(p), BackgroundIndex(bi),...
              PillarIndex(pii), Radius(r)];
              Transdata = FDTD_exec_pillars_parfor(pitch);
              cellframe2(ph,p,bi,pii,r) = Transdata;
          end
      end
    end
  end
end


% Path used to execute simulation in FDTD package within function FDTD_exec_pillars_parfor
[x1,y1]=system('"C:\Program Files\Lumerical\FDTD\bin\fdtd-solutions.exe" -run NOMAD_script.lsf');
```

error message:

> "Error: MATLAB cannot determine whether "FDTD_exec_pillars_parfor" refers to a function or variable. See Parallel for Loops in MATLAB, "Unambiguous Variable Names"."

This error message appeared after I added the two poolobj lines in attempt to resolve this error:

> "An UndefinedFunction error was thrown on the workers for 'FDTD_exec_pillars_parfor'. This might be because the file containing 'FDTD_exec_pillars_parfor' is not accessible on the workers. Use addAttachedFiles(pool, files) to specify the required files to be attached. See the documentation for 'parallel.Pool/addAttachedFiles' for more details.
>
> Caused by: Undefined function 'FDTD_exec_pillars_parfor' for input arguments of type 'double'"

Comment: Is 'FDTD_exec_pillars_parfor' available on the workers? Did you try using `addAttachedFiles` as directed?

Comment: You may need to put the file name in quotes.

Comment: @SamRoberts is correct - I don't know whether this is the only problem but as it stands MATLAB is trying to interpret `FDTD_exec_pillars_parfor.m` as either an object with a `.m` property or a struct with a `.m` field. It needs to be a character vector or a cell array of character vectors.